# New close reasons: unclear, too broad, opinion-based, and custom sub-reasons off-topic

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

There will be changes in [close reasons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) in the next few days:

- “not constructive” and “not a real question” are replaced by

  - “unclear what you're asking”
  - “too broad”
  - “primarily opinion-based”
- “off-topic” can be refined with predefined sub-reasons. These sub-reasons can cover common motifs that are not obvious from the site name, or cases where we would formerly have used “too localized”, which will disappear.
- Closed questions will be labelled as “on hold” for 5 days, and “closed” afterwards.

Should we have predefined close reasons?

Comment: Do we have a vote in this?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra - In which part? Not the main changes, but for the sub reasons for off topic.

Comment: Is this just for those who can actually cast close votes or for flagging as well?

Comment: @batpigandme - I am assuming that the flags will also change to reflect the new close reasons.

Comment: A very nice set of close reasons - http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/179/what-should-our-list-of-close-reasons-look-like/180#180

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the most recent questions that have been closed as off-topic, I see:

- A question on Drupal that probably should have been closed as NARQ
- An overly broad web development question
- A web app feature request
- A question on how easy it would be to install some software (presumably a web app); I think it should have been NARQ
- Asking for experiences in unsolicited contact of people through social media
- A question about building a Facebook app
- A question about Gmail on Android security (migrated to Android Enthusiasts)
- A question about integrating Google Play Music into a Linux music player
- A question about legal characters in email
- A question about integrating contacts on an Android phone with a task manager (migrated to Android Enthusiasts)
- A question on browser functionality (migrated to Super User)
- A request for web app recommendations for "lifetime" email addresses; probably should have been closed as NC
- A JavaScript error in someone's code
- A request for web app recommendations for a clothing store; should have been closed as NC
- A question about embedding reports in a web app someone is developing
- An app recommendation for translating PDFs; probably should have been closed as NC
- A request for a web app recommendation for community management; probably should have been closed as NC
- A programming issue with Google Maps
- A problem with a Facebook app being developed
- A question about email addresses with Salesforce.com. (There is apparently a saleforce.stackexchange.com)
- A request for a web app recommendation for data entry. I would expect NC
- A request for a web site so someone can re-build iGoogle
- A PHP programming question
- A question about playing audio in a web app being developed
- A question on how to get Microsoft Outlook to send/receive Gmail. Migrated to Super User
- A problem with putting a Facebook "Like" button on a web page. Migrated to Stack Overflow
- An overly broad JavaScript question. There's so little information, though, it could arguably have been closed as NARQ
- A request for recommendation of a website to "communicate" with contractors. NARQ or NC would have been better, I think
- A question about the security of third-party authentication in a custom web app. Migrated to Webmasters
- A question about code mysteriously appearing on a custom web site
- A JavaScript question. Migrated to Stack Overflow
- A request for recommendations of a simple online SQL database
- A question on a keyboard shortcut in Google Chrome
- A question about a hacked WordPress installation
- A question about Google's Pagespeed service for a custom app. Migrated to Webmasters

All of this is in addition to several successfully migrated questions (to Web Masters) asking about Google Search and SEO.

Clearly we need a custom reason:

> you're asking a question about building a web application. Programming questions should go on [Stack Overflow]

Since we don't want to migrate "crap", we should probably also cover:

- SEO
- Maintaining your own site/installation
- Browsers and other desktop software
- Bug Tracker question: The question is more of a feature-request/bug report for the web app and is better asked as a question to the webapp developer

But otherwise I think (so far) the new reasons cover most issues.

Comment: Is it no longer possible to mark a question as off-topic if it's not covered by an SE site in the flag listing? (e.g. Android questions)

Comment: @bat: You should probably ask this as a separate meta question.